# Definition of "left-invariant connection"

Tags: lie-groups, connections

I'm reading a paper which formulates a theorem which holds for a "left-invariant connection" on a Lie group *G*. I would guess that a connection is left invariant iff

$$\nabla_{dL_g X}dL_g Y = dL_g (\nabla_{X}Y)$$

For all vector fields $X,Y$ on *G*, and all $g \in G$.

However, I haven't found any reference for this definition. Could anyone point me to some ressource which defines and discusses left-invariant connections?

Comment: Example 8.2.3 [here](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~andrews/DG/DG_chap8.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, but I should have mentioned that I already looked at those notes and definition. It seems non-standard. For example it defines *the* left-invariant connection, wheres I have only seen the concept mentioned as a *class* of connections.

Answer (score 0):

The book "Geometry VI - Riemannian geometry" by Postnikov includes a chapter on left-invariant connections. He defines as follows,

[image]

wether this is equivalent to the above guess at a definition, I don't know.